# I accidentally resized my EFI partition and now it's 128GB and I want some space back . What should I do?

Tags: partitioning

I had 128GB free space from a previous Windows installed that I removed recently and while trying to move that space into the Linux filesystem partition I accidentally put it into the EFI partition and now I can't undo it. I need some help to remove that extra space and if possible a solution for fusing the free space with the filesystem partition already existing.

EDIT:

[image: parted]

Comment: You cannot edit mounted partitions, so you have to use live installer. The ESP can be 300 to 500MB, Windows often uses 100MB which is a bit small but works if just two installs. post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: Edited, thank you for replying

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Better to post terminal output as text, code, not as graphic. Normally the ESP is first partition, but since smaller drive its ok. You will have to shrink left, move right & then can expand ext4 partition. Do each step in gparted from live installer, do not queue steps.

Comment: Can you explain me how to do this ?